# What's the best way to develop an multi country application?

Tags: architecture, e-commerce, currency, multilingual, software-distribution

i'm developing an application that's can run in many countries. For example, the app will sell tickets where the ticket can be selled in dollar, euro, brazillian real and other. The buyer will pay in his currency but I need to do the conversion. I want to know if existis a good practice to develop an application like that.

I must save in TICKET table the currency of seller and when someone to buy, do the conversion or what? I don't know if i've been understandable but I need some help here. I don't find any article to solve my questions.

Comment: Your question if very broad and will most likely spark an [opinionated debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions).  You might want to consider the application type your going to develop (mobile, web, desktop) and search the web for strategies for handling them.  If you have some very specific coding issues afterwards, Stack Overflow is the place to seek those answers.

Comment: I'll use a web api has the back end of all clients (mobile, desktop, web) so I want to know a good way to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got you right then I think so you are looking for a currency converter functionality for your application?

For which you should develop your application on WordPress and use currency converter plugin like [Open Currency Converter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/artiss-currency-converter/).

If you still have any concern please feel free to ask.

Comment: Not just that. I'm talking about language, currency, datetime. Exists an article, by example, that can help me?

Comment: Will let you know if I would come across any such article